# Group data in Lead/Opportunity/sObject

Tags: administration, developer, customization

Can anyone assist me on to how to group data in Leads/Opportunity ?
Note: I am not building reports.
I have thousands of records in standard object which I want to show them in groups/folders/lists.Grouping can be in form of folders, or multiple lists.
Grouping can be by city, country or Language fields.
I have thousands of records, It will save time for searching a specific record of a particular type.

***Any assistance will highly appreciated.
Advance thanks.***

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more specificity about what you're trying to do and what you've tried so far. Are you building a Report? A List View? Browsing records? Writing a SOQL query? (Please [edit], don't comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce provides two functional areas to display grouped and filtered records in the UI:

- Reports (and dashboards built upon them)
- List views

There is no such thing as a record folder in Salesforce.

It sounds like what you need is [List Views](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_customization/lex_customization_list). You may create multiple List Views on each sObject, and each List View may apply one or many filters, such as by city, country, and language fields. You can then expose these List Views to your users.

Comment: It looks like it will work, let me give it a try.